Unity & Playfab Sending friend requests to offline players
public void SaveFriendRequest(string targetPlayerId, string senderDisplayName)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { senderDisplayName, "pending" } // "pending" indicates that the request is pending
    };

    var request = new UpdateUserDataRequest
    {
        PlayFabId = targetPlayerId, // Use the recipient's PlayFab ID here
        Data = data,
        Permission = UserDataPermission.Public // or Private, depending on your needs
    };

    PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserData(request, OnDataUpdateSuccess, OnDataUpdateFailure);
}

Hey guys! I am dealing with sending membership requests in my game and I am having a problem with the function that is supposed to save the membership request sent to the player. It is not working now and there is even an ERROR: 'UpdateUserDataRequest' does not contain a definition for 'PlayFabId'
Maybe the function should be written differently?
Could someone please guide me how exactly do I change something for a player who is not me? Like saving the friend request I sent him while he was not connected to the game.

UpdateUserDataRequest does not have a field PlayFabId.  Documentation

public void SaveFriendRequest(string targetPlayerId)
{
    var request = new ExecuteCloudScriptRequest
    {
        FunctionName = "SaveFriendRequest",
        FunctionParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "targetPlayerId", targetPlayerId }
        },
        GeneratePlayStreamEvent = true
    };

    PlayFabClientAPI.ExecuteCloudScript(request, OnCloudScriptSuccess, OnCloudScriptFailure);
}


Well, then I solved the problem by adding the SaveFriendRequest function in Cloud Script in Playfab:

handlers.SaveFriendRequest = function (args, context) {
    var targetPlayerId = args.targetPlayerId;
    var senderPlayerId = currentPlayerId; 

    var playerData = server.GetUserData({
        PlayFabId: targetPlayerId,
        Keys: ["FriendRequests"] 
    });

    var friendRequests = [];
    if (playerData.Data && playerData.Data.FriendRequests) {
        friendRequests = JSON.parse(playerData.Data.FriendRequests.Value);
    }

    friendRequests.push(senderPlayerId);

    server.UpdateUserData({
        PlayFabId: targetPlayerId,
        Data: {
            "FriendRequests": JSON.stringify(friendRequests)
        }
    });

    return { message: "Friend request saved successfully!" };
};


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
